# Joda TIme: can't format 12 hours datetime

Tags: java, date, parsing, time, jodatime

I'm trying to parse some dates that can be both 24 or 12 hours format using JodaTime. The 24-hours formatter works well, but when it comes to a 12-hours date it crashes with error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "10/14/2015 10:26:21 PM" is malformed at " PM"
```

I'm parsing dates that looks like this: "10/15/2015 04:46:32 PM"

java code:

```
private final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
private final String DATE_FORMAT_12 = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa";

DateTimeFormatter dateStringFormat = null;
String temp = jsonAlarm.getString("received_time_string");

if(temp.contains("AM") || temp.contains("PM"))
    dateStringFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT_12);
else
    dateStringFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);

if(!temp.equals(""))
    alarm.setReceivedTime(dateStringFormat.parseDateTime(temp));

temp = jsonAlarm.getString("timestamp_string");

if(temp.contains("AM") || temp.contains("PM"))
    dateStringFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT_12);
else
    dateStringFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);

if(!temp.equals(""))
    alarm.setTimestamp(dateStringFormat.parseDateTime(temp));
```

the if statements that select the formatter works. so I don't what I'm doing wrong.

please help
thanks

UPDATE: I checked the value of temp in debug and as far as I can see the "space" before PM is a proper space. also changing the if to `if(temp.contains(" AM") || temp.contains(" PM"))` works and correctly set the formatter with the 12 hours pattern

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Make sure that the blank space before the `PM` is space, and not some other character.

Comment: is malformed at " PM" check what is in received_time_string

Comment: can you point me how to do this?

Comment: I checked the value of temp in debug and as far as I can see the "space" before PM is a proper space.

also changing the if to `if(temp.contains(" AM") || temp.contains(" PM"))` works and correctly set the formatter with the 12 hours pattern